# CSS Создание свечения через conic-gradient?

Tags: css, css3, html5

Подскажите, есть ли возможность средствами CSS сделать свечение указанное в примере

```css
.shineBlock{
  background: #f00;

}
```

```html
<div class="shineBlock">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlackStar1991/Pictures-for-sharing-/master/shine/shine.png" alt="shine"/>
</div>
```

Собственно вопрос возникает в том есть ли способ задания прозрачности ?

Comment: возможно это поможет https://cssgradient.io/

Comment: Немного не то, или я не понимаю, как это может помочь сделать плавный переход от белого к прозрачному

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.opacity{
background: rgb(255,255,255);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
width:100%;
height: 700px;
background-color:red;
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 65% 100%, 31% 100%);
border-radius:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="opacity"></div>
```

Comment: Осталось только понять как из этого сделать конус) Ну знаешь как свет от софитов

Comment: изменил код. максимум так я могу

Comment: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ зайдите сюда выберите подходящую форму скопируйте ссылку который генерируется внизу и ставьте на див в css